# Wordpress error in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been working with Wordpress for last few years but I face a  weird issue (Wordpress 4.1) on my new CentOS 6.6 with php 5.5.20 version. I tried thrice the installation and now I write this up.

Note:--> No file permissions issues.Apache is group and owner of the file with 755 and 644 permission on server.

I got the following errors on my admin:

1)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,thickbox,underscore,backbone,wp-util,wp-ba…:323
```

(line no.)

2)

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,thickbox,underscore,backbone,wp-util,wp-ba…:2(line no.) Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Please Advise.

Comment: The only thing i can tell you now, is that that function is used to translate strings. It seems there is something wrong with the inclusion of classes files.

Did you check the apache and php error logs?

Comment: @Aerendir thanks, but nothing found in error and access log,Seems like javascript or Jqery script error.Should i wait for next release of wordpress?